# Cookie for Google App Engine request - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm working on an app which uses an API that requires me to make a first Post request to authenticate.

Looking the authenticate response, I've seen that a cookie was created: ApiCredentials=....

So I authenticate:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url = url, method = urlfetch.POST)
api_credential = result.headers['set-cookie']
```

and then I create a request with that cookie in the header

```
urlfetch.fetch(url = url, method = urlfetch.GET, headers = {'Cookie': api_credential})
```

The problem is: in dev everything works perfectly, but when I deploy, it doesn't work. In the logs I can see the cookie that was recieved.

API link: http://www.sptrans.com.br/desenvolvedores/APIOlhoVivo/Documentacao.aspx?1 (portuguese)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question does not show the cookie name `ApiCredentials`.  It may be that in development, there was only a single cookie and in production there are more, in which case `result.headers['set-cookie']` returns multiple values comma separated.

The [URL Fetch Response Objects](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects) page suggests retrieving multiple headers of the same name in a list by calling `result.header_msg.getheaders('set-cookie')` instead and then finding `ApiCredentials` in the resulting list.

It might be safer to say 'Set-Cookie' in case-sensitive environments.